# Selecting snapped vertices of different two features individually by QGIS 3.X vertex tool

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2, vertices

[image: feature 1]

[image: feature 2, the vertex snap on feature 1]

In QGIS 2, I can use node tool,

1. click on feature 2
2. click on the vertex (of feature 2) to select it.
3. Delete it.

[image: QGIS3 vertex tool]

I QGIS 3, by using vertex tool, I can't select which feature I want to modify, it changes automatic by the mouse cursor.
I need to mouse over the part of feature 2 and move carefully to the vertex.

How can I chose which vertex I want to select by vertex tool if these vertices are all snap in same coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the docs it appears if you right click a feature in the vertex editor it will lock to that feature (*Note this is introduced at QGIS 3.4*):

> Right click on a feature will immediately show the vertex editor and lock this feature, thus disabling the editing of any other features. While being locked, a feature is exclusive for editing: Selecting and moving of vertices and segments by clicking or dragging is only possible for this feature. New vertices can only be added to the locked feature.

Alternatively, you could select a vertex next to or near the one you want and cycle through the table to grab the correct one.

I.e. Select a vertex from the correct feature where it is not overlapping (so you can easily select it), then cycle up/down through the table in the Panel until it highlights the one you wanted to delete.

See docs below for more info on the Panel.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-vertex-editor-panel

Comment: Yes as mentioned they have changed the default behaviors. If the answer solved your question then please "Accept" it so others can see this is the solution clearly.

Comment: thank you, I feel that the left-click of node-tool (2) is similar to right-click of vertex-tool (3). However, I don't know how to "unlock" (back to the original behavior of vertex tool, focus on features by mouse cursor over).

Comment: Oh, I edit the comment for tooooo long time. lol.

Comment: I assume to unlock it, you just right click the feature again, although it doesn't actually say in the docs